# How can I append more nodes in this doubly linked list by using my pointers and structures?

Tags: c++, append, doubly-linked-list

I'm not getting any errors, but I am not able to append songs to the doubly linked list.`I do not currently have any delete operators because I plan on adding them near the end of creating the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Song
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string singerName;
};

struct Node
{
    Song sg;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

struct FirstSong
{
    Node* first;
};

Node *getLastSong(FirstSong *head);
void addSong(FirstSong *head, Node *tail);
Node *removeSong(FirstSong *head, int index);
void displayListElements(FirstSong *head);
void clearList(FirstSong *head);

int main()
{
    Node* tail;
    FirstSong* head;
    int choice;
    int ID;
    string name;
    string singer;

    //Creating the first node
    head = new FirstSong;
    head->first = new Node;
    cout << "What is your song's number" << endl;
    cin >> ID;
    head->first->sg.id = ID;

    cout << "What is the name of your song?" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    head->first->sg.name = name.c_str();

    cout << "What is the name of your singer?" << endl;
    getline(cin, singer);
    head->first->sg.singerName = singer.c_str();

    head->first->prev = NULL;
    tail = head->first;



    //Prompting user for what they want to do
    cout << "What would you like to do now?" << endl;
labelA:
    cout << "1 - add song" << endl;
    cout << "2 - remove song" << endl;
    cout << "3 - show last song" << endl;
    cout << "4 - display all songs" << endl;
    cout << "5 - clear songs" << endl;
    cout << "6 - quit" << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    //Switch statement will be right here

    return 0;
}


Node *getLastSong(FirstSong *head)
{
}


void addSong(FirstSong *head, Node *tail)
{

    Node* n;
    char choice;
    int ID;
    string name;
    string singer;

myLabelB:
    if(tail->next == NULL){
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Not NULL" << endl;
    }
    n = new Node;
    cout << "What is your song's number" << endl;
    cin >> ID;
    n->sg.id = ID;

    cout << "What is the name of your song?" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);

    n->sg.name = name.c_str();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What is the name of your singer?" << endl;

    getline(cin, singer);
    n->sg.singerName = singer.c_str();
    n->prev = tail;
    tail->next = n;
    tail = n;

    cout << "Add another song?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
    {
        goto myLabelB;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
}

Node *removeSong(FirstSong *head, int index)
{
}

void displayListElements(FirstSong *head)
{
    Node* temp = head->first;

    while(temp != NULL){
        cout << temp->sg.id << " ";
        cout << temp->sg.name << " ";
        cout << temp->sg.singerName << " " << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

What can I do to append the new songs without deleting the old ones? My guess is that I am somehow setting the newest Node = NULL, but I can't find where.

Comment: Usually, double-linked lists are kept using a pointer to `first` *and* a pointer to `last`. Then adding an element at the end of the list is as simple as changing `last->next` and then updating `last` to reflect this.

Comment: My `first` is `head` and my `last` is `tail`. Did I not link them correctly?

Comment: I must say I really didn't feel like reading through all your code: it's absolutely not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I can say you should have a `last` member in `FirstNode`

Comment: Alright. I apologize for the overload of code. I didn't want to leave out anything important